# How to unmount gmail account from "Places" in Ubuntu after adding via Thunderbird

Tags: files, thunderbird, gmail

When setting up Thunderbird on my Ubuntu 20.04 system, I added my gmail account to it. My Google Drive account also showed up. I decided against using Thunderbird and canceled my account on it. However, my gmail account and my Google Drive still appear in my file manager and I don't want them to. How do I permanently stop my gmail account from appearing in my file manager? (I don't anyone to be able to access my gmail account from my computer.) Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Per a reply on Twitter I received from @linuxuprising, go to Online Accounts in Settings, and delete my google account there. It worked. So simple, yet so difficult to find that answer. Big thanks to @linuxuprising.